# Cursor-type for MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, cursor

I have a MySQL Cursor, but I need to set it as read-only and not-scrollable, but how can I set it in the stored procedure?

My stored procedure looks like

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `GetAllNonprocessedSMSes` €€
CREATE PROCEDURE `GetAllNonprocessedSMSes`()
   BEGIN
      ...
      DECLARE id_cur CURSOR FOR
         SELECT `id` FROM (
            SELECT
               MIN(`id`) AS `id`
            FROM
               `inbox`
            WHERE
               `Processed`='false'
               AND `udh`=''
         ) AS `baseview`
      ORDER BY `id`;

      DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET finish = TRUE;

      OPEN id_cur;
      the_loop : LOOP
         FETCH id_cur INTO smsid;
         ...
      END LOOP the_loop;

      ...
   END €€
```

Comment: Why would you want your cursor to be "read only and not scrollable"?  Surely, if that were the case, your loop wouldn't work as intended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't mention which version of MySql you are using, but according to the [MySQL 5.0 reference manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cursors.html):

"MySQL supports cursors inside stored programs. The syntax is as in embedded SQL. Cursors have these properties:
- Asensitive: The server may or may not make a copy of its result table
- Read only: Not updatable
- Nonscrollable: Can be traversed only in one direction and cannot skip rows"

Therefore, I would say that MySql cursors are, by definition, read-only AND nonscrollable !

Comment: As I understand, it could have the properties, but they don't necessary have them. I am using 5.1.61

Comment: MySql 5.0, 5.1, 5.5 and 5.6 are all the same. Cursors are read-only and nonscrollable. Perhaps there is a misunderstanding with the definition; non scrollable means the cursor will move through the rows of data (in one direction only) and cannot skip any rows. As far as I know, there is nothing to set in your stored procedure. Check the MySql reference link above for more info.